# Nginx compressing 5B data to 1.03 KB how to discard this compression?

Tags: nginx, gzip

I have used gzip compression in my Nginx with compression level 9.

Then I can see 5B data is compressed to  1KB?

Could not know the reason and how to avoid to discard compress for less than 10B ?

[Firefox Origianl and Compressed size ration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uvD1.png)

Comment: 5B is smaller than 1KB so it must be the other way around?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [gzip_min_length](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html#gzip_min_length) directive to avoid compressing small objects. Default minimal size is 20.

Comment: Could you please provide a  value which will not compress files with less than 1kb size.